# is there any way to read from text file word by word (i.e without using split)?

Tags: java

is there any way to read from text file word by word (i.e without using split)? . I am  able to read line by line directly with nextLine() with a scanner object, but I got error when  I tried with next(). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have against split?

Comment: Post the code. What's wrong with .split(SPACE)?

Comment: Take a look at stringtokenizer.

Comment: No, you can read line by line. Then split each line into words.

Comment: so implements your own buffered reader class :)